# Difference between #adb shell vs #adb -e shell while running adb shell command

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Difference between **#adb shell** vs  **#adb -e shell** while running adb shell command ???

I was trying to execute both of the above commands and seems like they are totally same in running?

Is there any specific reasons or any other?

Comment: Why not to check adb help? The answer to your question is obvious - "-e Direct an adb command to the only running emulator"

Answer (score 3):

You can easily google the [answer](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#directingcommands)

> If you have multiple devices available, but only one is an emulator, use the -e option to send commands to the emulator. Likewise, if there are multiple devices but only one hardware device attached, use the -d option to send commands to the hardware device.